# Openvpn with TCP setup, but failed to connect through another client from Centos

Tags: centos, openvpn

I created two different server, Server A is for openvpn server, Server B is the client.

Below is my client information.

```
client
tls-client
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/client.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/client.key
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/myvpn.tlsauth
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"
port 1194
proto tcp
remote 101.xxx.xxx.xxx
dev tun
topology subnet
pull
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
```

Log

```
Wed Jan 30 11:32:01 2019 137.116.132.54:33294 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Wed Jan 30 11:32:01 2019 137.116.132.54:33294 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Wed Jan 30 11:33:11 2019 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]137.116.132.54:33500
Wed Jan 30 11:33:12 2019 137.116.132.54:33500 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]137.116.132.54:33500, sid=903433b4 467fca08
Wed Jan 30 11:33:12 2019 137.116.132.54:33500 tls-crypt unwrap error: packet authentication failed
Wed Jan 30 11:33:12 2019 137.116.132.54:33500 TLS Error: tls-crypt unwrapping failed from [AF_INET]137.116.132.54:33500
```

I have check the both port, the needed port is opened. What else can check for this?

Comment: Did you intentionally wrap the log output?

Comment: What do you mean by wrap the log output?

Comment: You did something like word wrap to the log output, see the first version of the post.

Answer (score 0):

> What else can check for this?

I would check the meanings of the content of the logs you posted. They are almost certainly cause by a quite specific set of circumstances. You can check the meanings of your error messages by using a search engine of your choice.

Comment: Yes, i do check, i change it from the UDP to TCP .But based on the log file, kept say the Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co)